# I'm having difficulty switching my IEnumerable<T> implementation to ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable, icollection

This is driving me bonkers, so I figured I'd toss it up to the community rather than bang my head against my desk.

I'm switching out an area of my application from using IEnumerable to ICollection.
I have several Extension Methods defined in IEnumerableOfIInterfaceExtensions that I want to translate into ICollectionOfIInterfaceExtensions and after I've switched everything out under the covers but when I switch out the collection on my repository, I get the (unexpected) error:

```
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Bar' and the best extension method overload 'Application.Data.Repositories.RepositoryExtensions.Bar(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Application.Domain.Models.IInterface>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Application.Domain.Models.IInterface>)' has some invalid arguments
```

This only pops up when I try to use ICollection rather than IEnumerable. 
My implementation with IEnumerable

**[Edit** I've updated to add my class definition for clarity. IDataRepository contains a single method "Retrieve" that returns an IEnumerable and IEntityRepository contains a single void method "Save" that accepts an IInterface

```
public class Repository<T>: IDataRepository<T>,IEntityRepository<T>
                        where T: class, IInterface
{
    protected virtual IEnumerable<T> Collection{ get; set;}
    public virtual void Bar(T thing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Collection == null) return;
            Collection = (IEnumerable<T>)Collection.Foo(thing);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //breakpoint for debugging
        }
    }
}
```

Foo's signature as IEnumerable

```
internal static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static IEnumerable<IInterface> Foo(this ICollection<IInterface> c1,
                                                    IEnumerable<IInterface> c2)
    {
        //implementation removed for posting
        return c1;
    }
internal static IEnumerable<IInterface> Foo(this IEnumerable<IInterface> c1,
                                                    IInterface thing)
    {
        return Foo(c1, new List<IInterface>() { thing });
    }
}
```

As an IEnumerable, CodeLens reports that each Foo has 1 reference. The client calls into the second one which wraps around the first one.  Whenever I switch these to ICollection, my references in CodeLens disappear and I get the exception I posted above...which makes no sense seeing as how I *have* extension methods on ICollection at the point the exception is thrown.  Here is Foo's interface using ICollections

```
protected virtual ICollection<T> Collection { get; set;}
    public virtual void Bar(T thing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Collection == null) return;
            Collection = (ICollection<T>)Collection.Foo(entity);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //breakpoint
        }
    }

internal static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static ICollection<IInterface> Foo(this ICollection<IInterface> c1,
                                                    IEnumerable<IInterface> c2)
    {
        //implementation removed for posting
        return c1;
    }
    internal static ICollection<IInterface> Foo(this ICollection<IInterface> c1,
                                                    IInterface thing)
    {
        return Foo(cache, new List<IInterface>() { thing });
    }
}
```

Can anyone identify what the problem is when switching this over to an ICollection from an IEnumerable?

Comment: Where is the bar extension method? Also can you show how you're using it?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to invoke your extension method on something that is only IEnumerable<T> and not an ICollection<T>?

Comment: Also, why perform a cast from IEnumerable to IEnumerable, same with ICollection in your second example.

Comment: Oh this is a covariance problem. Your collection is IEnumerable<T> but your extensions are IEnumerable<IInterface>.

Comment: @mwrichardson I left my IEnumerableOfIInterface extensions in place when I built out the ICollectionOfIInterface extensions.  I switched "Collection" over from IEnumerable to ICollection and poof.

Comment: @sircodesalot [re: covariance]  The puzzling thing is that everything works fine when I'm sitting with IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerableExtension<IInterface>. It's only when I switch over to ICollection that this becomes a problem, which is what's left me scratching my head

Comment: @sircodesalot [re: covariance] Allow me also to clarify that my Repository that contains method Foo has T constrained to be a class as well as IInterface. I'll update my post to provide

Comment: @K.AlanBates What sircodesalot said is right. `Collection is ICollection<T>` is true. `Collection is IEnumerable<T>` is true. `Collection is ICollection<IInterface>` is false. `Collection is IEnumerable<IInterface>` is true. You define your extension method on `ICollection<IInterface>`, but your collection doesn't implement that interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covariance problem. **`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, `ICollection<T>` is not**.

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

You can see the `out` keyword only in `IEnumerable<T>` declaration.

That's why your extension method works only for `ICollection<IInterface>`, and not for `ICollection<ClassWhichImplementsIInterface>`.

Make your extension methods generic to make it work:

```
internal static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static ICollection<T> Foo<T>(this ICollection<T> c1, IEnumerable<T> c2) where T : IInterface
    {
        //implementation removed for posting
        return c1;
    }
    internal static ICollection<T> Foo<T>(this ICollection<T> c1, T thing) where T : IInterface
    {
        return Foo(cache, new List<T>() { thing });
    }
}
```

or

```
internal static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static ICollection<IInterface> Foo<T>(this ICollection<IInterface> c1, IEnumerable<T> c2) where T : IInterface
    {
        //implementation removed for posting
        return c1;
    }
    internal static ICollection<IInterface> Foo<T>(this ICollection<T> c1, T thing) where T : IInterface
    {
        return Foo(cache, new List<IInterface>() { thing });
    }
}
```

Depending what you want it to return: `ICollection<IInterface>` or `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Ahh...I did not know that about ICollection. Thanks

Comment: (To clarify: I didn't realize we were discussing container type covariance. I thought we were discussing the entity being contained, which is why I kept coming back to the constraints being used on the type when posters identified this as a covariance issue.  I didn't realize that Microsoft fixed their collection covariance bug only for IEnumerable. I thought they had fixed it for all collection types. Learned something)

Comment: @K.AlanBates There is no way to have strongly typed covariant collection with `Add` method. That's just not possible. And that's why only `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant - that's read-only collection which only allows enumeration over elements.